# Could not find form id in javascript function

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, coffeescript

I am registering a new user using devise. My form id is "`new_user`". I am using validation.js plugin for client side validation. On sign up I want to call a function from coffeescript.

```
#= require validation.js.coffee
formValidation = ->

  validate_form = new Validation("Forms")
  validate_form.validate_registration_form "#new_user" if $("#new_user").length


formValidation()
```

After click while debugging in browsers console, control enters in this function and I got `$("#new_user").length` as 0 . And when control leave this function I got `$("#new_user").length` as 1.

Not able to understand why that id disappeared. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly when is this function called? I suspect it's before the DOM is ready.

Comment: yes.. before the DOM is ready. What would be the way to call it?

Comment: Well, it should be called _after_ your form DOM is ready. Wrap it in `jQuery.ready ->` function or something.

Comment: Added function inside jQuery.ready -> . But now the function is not being called when I submit my form

Comment: I think it wasn't being called upon submit earlier either. You have to add invocation of this method to submit handler somewhere.

Comment: My bad...I added function definition instead of function call inside document.ready... now its corrected and working.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

i can't help you for coffeescript i will tell you in js formate

create one js file write below code and assign some id for user form. I will take sample 'user_form' id for user form.

```
$('#user_form').validate({
    rules: {
    'user[first_name]': {required: true, email: true},
    'user[last_name]': {required: true, email: true}
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) { 
        if ($(form).valid()) form.submit(); return false; 
    }
});
```

i hope this code will be helpful for you